# How to find facebook post id

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

Can anyone help me find the Facebook Post ID? For example,
with this post URL: https://www.facebook.com/ProgrammersCreateLife/posts/pfbid02MLykkN9jHgjWpWXuvN5LSv5dS2em8eyFHSeNCeS9vfjCB4tJexBT3FaLNPe3X2Eol

it can be accessed through the Post ID URL:
https://www.facebook.com/670443951778088

I just need to know how to find the Post ID, such as 670443951778088. Please assist me if you know the method.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible; Facebook is using those cryptic URLs for a reason. When getting posts from the Feed API for a page you have access to, you will get usable IDs.